# What are the advantages of 'Stateless Function Components' over 'ES6 Class Components'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I often read that I should use 'Stateless Function Components' if possible, but mostly without any explanation why. What are the benefits?

Comment: Googling both of those phrases each turned up with [this article](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) as the first result. It lists the benefits. This is too broad for SO though. Perhaps you should read some articles, and then come back and explain what you know and don't know.

Comment: I read that article. They just gave so little information about the benefits. I think it would be helpful for me and other to get some more detail from SO on it.

Comment: Interesting. "Put on hold". That's completely valid and normal question. Good answer is short, and there are not "too many" of them (do you actually see "too many answers" or something which is "too long"? _Neither_ of that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, stateless function components renders faster, as there's an optimized short-path for them in React rendering pipeline.

Second, the code is much cleaner, since you're typing less and there are almost no visual noise. If you use modern JS, of course. Check it out, I'm defining some "custom tag":

```
const MyFancyDiv = ({ children, ...otherProps }) => (
    <div { ...otherProps } className='i-am-fancy-wrapper'>
        { children }
    </div>
);
```

For everything which doesn't have a state, context, or custom lifecycle methods this is the preferred way.

And it's actually the feature of React which makes it very hard to beat for any other framework. Use it when you can.

Comment: Not an advantage, but maybe worth noting: Functional components don’t have instances at all. Class components have instances, but you never need to create a component instance directly—React takes care of this.

Comment: Yes, it's one of the reasons why they are rendered faster. No instances, no lifecycle hooks, simplified rendering path.